# spectrum of multiplicative morphisms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, sp.spectral-theory

Let $T:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a continuous map, which is neither surjective nor injective. Put
$$
C([0,1])\ni f\mapsto \Phi(f):=f\circ T\in C([0,1]).
$$
Notice that, under the above conditions, $0\in\sigma(\Phi)$.

I'm searching for an example of $\Phi$ as above such that 
$$
0<\operatorname{dist}\left(\sigma_{ph}(\Phi),(\sigma(\Phi)\setminus\sigma_{ph}(\Phi))\right)<1,
$$
where $\sigma_{ph}$ stands for "peripheral spectrum".

I'm also searching for examples $\Phi$ satisfying, additionally, 
$$
\sigma_{ph}(\Phi)\supsetneq\{1\}.
$$

Comment: Welcome on MathOverflow! Before I give an answer, may I ask where the questions stems from?

Comment: just to find an example of a multiplicative *-map such that the spectrum is neither included in the unit circle, nor consisting of the whole unit disc in the complex plane

Comment: Thank you for your response! Alright, but how/in which context did this question occur to you? (I'm asking because it seems a bit like a homework problem in an operator theory course to me.)

Comment: If it is an homework, please provide me an answer/reference

Comment: Well, my point was actually whether *you* were assigned this as a homework problem (which would make the question inappropriate for this site) - but I take your last comment as a "no" :-). My apologies for being maybe a bit over-skeptical. Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I adjusted the answer to the new version of the question.

Such an example does not exist. More precisely, for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous mapping $T: K \to K$ the associated Koopman operator $\Phi_T: C(K) \to C(K)$ (given by $\Phi_Tf = f \circ T$ for each $f \in C(K)$) has either the closed unit disk $\overline{D}$ as its spectrum, or the spectrum is contained in the union of the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ and $\{0\}$.

In fact, the following holds:

(i) If $T^{n+1}(K) \not= T^n(K)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, then every complex number $\lambda$ of modulus $|\lambda| < 1$ is an approximate eigenvalue of $\Phi_T$; in particlar, $\sigma(\Phi_T) = \overline{D}$.

(ii) If there exists a number $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $T^{n+1}(K) = T^n(K)$, then precisely one of the following two assertions holds:

- The open unit disk is contained in the point spectrum of the dual operator $(\Phi_T)'$ on $C(K)'$; in particular, $\sigma(\Phi_T) = \overline{D}$.
- We have $\sigma(\Phi_T) \subseteq \mathbb{T} \cup \{0\}$. In this case, we have $0 \in \sigma(\Phi_T)$ if and only if $T(K) \not= K$.

This was proved by E. Scheffold in Theorem 2.7 of his paper "[Das Spektrum von Verbandsoperatoren in Banachverbänden](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01110116)" (1971). Unfortunately, I do not know any reference where the result is proved (or merely stated) in English.

Comment: Many thanks, I was knowing such an example, but I was searching for something more involved

Comment: @fidaleo: Alright, then I suggest that you edit your question in order to describe more precisely what you are looking for / how involved the example should be.

Comment: Now it seems that the question is ok

Comment: Another good example might be something satisfying the question I raised, plus the condition that the peripheral spectrum includes properly 1.

Comment: @fidaleo: Thanks for the edit! This makes the question much more interesting, of course. I'll think about it...

Comment: Many thanks Jochen